# difference between ngx-bootstrap and ng2 bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I'm making project in bootstrap (UI) and angular 2. I'm new to both things
 My friend suggests me to use ng2 bootstrap I am so much confused between ngx bootstrap and ng2 bootstrap. Always when I search ng 2 bootstrap it take me to the ngx bootstrap. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ng2-bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap are one and the same: ng2-bootstrap was the old name, ngx-bootstrap is the new name. It's a project that's attempting to create an Angular-specific version of the Twitter Bootstrap components (i.e. no dependency on jQuery). The project is run by Valor Software. I don't have inside knowledge but my guess is that the name change happened when Angular rebranded itself as just 'Angular' (instead of Angular 2).

Comment: and then there's also something called `ng-bootstrap`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983791/angular-powered-bootstrap-is-ngx-bootstrap/45984098

Comment: Please use `ngx-bootstrap` everyone.  I don't find it as enjoyable moving onto the next contract with some random 3rd part component.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 33):

Since **Angular2** is released, many components are published as npm modules and most them have prefix - **ng2-** or **angular2-** like **ng2-bootstrap**, **angular2-tags-input**.

After releasing **Angular4**, all those node modules were faced with serious problem - **"Do we have to be renamed to ng4 or angular4???"**

Here is an answer written by Igor Minar from Angular Core Team.

http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

***"It’s just “Angular”"***

As you can see here, **Angular2** and **Angular4** are all **Angular**.

And Upgrading version is not painful anymore like 2 to 4.
Just do **ng upgrade** or **ncu -u -a**.

From now angular components should be **ngx-something**.

Answer (score 5):

ngx-bootstrap is Native Angular directives for Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4. Contains all core and not only Bootstrap components powered by Angular. Basically, it's the same thing, but ng2 is the old name for the ngx.