# Using angular-ui-bootstrap in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-forms, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I am using Angular2 with typescript. The dependencies are resolved using npm.

I want to use Modal dialog in my application. For this, I need to include angular-ui-bootstrap in my application. I need to angular-ui-bootstrap modal dialog in my application.

Comment: angular-ui-bootstrap is for AngularJS 1.x. But you can use ng-bootstrap for Angular 4.x (same idea, from the same team): https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home. Google is your friend.

Comment: could you help me to show a dialog using ng-bootstrap (NgbModal)

Comment: The page I linked to has several demos. Just look at the code. You can also open the demos in a plunkre to play with them by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

angular-ui-bootstrap is for AngularJS, for the new Angular you can try this one:

http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

or this one:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

The difference between those two project is discussed here: [What is the difference between "ng-bootstrap" and "ngx-bootstrap"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758400/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bootstrap-and-ngx-bootstrap)