# I am confused between "ngx-bootstrap" and "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am planning to use Bootstrap 4 with angular 4 in my project, but I am confused between `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`. So can anyone help me which is better for angular 4?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758400/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bootstrap-and-ngx-bootstrap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "ng-bootstrap" and "ngx-bootstrap"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758400/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bootstrap-and-ngx-bootstrap)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are good, you can flip a coin and use any of one.

I am `ng-bootstrap` for my projects, so far no problem.

But selecting a framework can be tricky, you should consider many facts.

First both support `Angular 4` and  `Bootstrap 4`, but `ngx-bootstrap` support  `Bootstrap 3` too.

While checking in to the closed questions in github `ngx-bootstrap` wins, check these links [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed), [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed).

`ngx-bootstrap` team also has more modules like `ng2-file-upload` more [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-plans)

and also check Stackoverflow unanswered questions [ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ng-bootstrap), [ngx-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ngx-bootstrap). That means there is more chance for ngx-bootstrap problems get answered in SO.

Answer (score 3):

`@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and `ngx-bootstrap` both refer to **different implementations** of Bootstrap Components for Angular(2+). They are both implemented by different teams, with the same goal, that is to provide bootstrap components in Angular(2+) without the use of jquery.

As for your question of which one is better, the answer would depend on your requirements. `ngx-bootstrap` supports both Bootstrap 4 Alpha and Bootstrap 3 (with a patch). ng-bootstrap **only** supports Bootstrap 4. If you used the `ui-bootstrap` library for angularjs, it's worth noting that `ng-bootstrap` was developed by the same team that developed `ui-bootstrap`. Other than that, you can explore each of their APIs to determine which one you can work with better.

**ngx-bootstrap**: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

**@ng-bootstrap**: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 0):

Best way to quickly integrate Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 Components with Angular use ngx-bootstrap npm packs. ngx-bootstrap contains all core (and not only) Bootstrap components powered by Angular. So you don't need to include original JS components, but we are using markup and css provided by Bootstrap.

**Install ngx-bootstrap from npm using**

> npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

**If you need bootstrap 3 styles include**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**If you need bootstrap 4 styles include**

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[More info](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

Enjoy Happy codeing. Hopefully that helps!