# How to use bootstrap inside angular project?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap in my Angular project.
For this purpose I installed Bootstrap with this command:
`npm install bootstrap` and I added this reference:

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

in styles property in angular.json file.

After that I try to run my application, but on the component I don't see that Bootstrap is applied on template:

```
<div>
  <!-- Actual search box -->
  <div class="form-group has-search">
    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why is Bootstrap not applied on template?

Answer (score 0):

You use the css from the bootstrap

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

You don't use the bootstrap JavaScript, you install `ngx-bootstrap`

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/

Comment: Adrian thanks for post.What if I dont need bootstrap javascript I only need the style, no animation or stuff like that.

Comment: Just import the styles from a CDN. Put this line in the header of your index.html https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

When installing bootstrap `npm install --save bootstrap` , use `--save`, Otherwise it will work only in your local machine. Because it will not save in the `package.json`.

In angular.json file and add bootstrap path:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bootstrap in Angular project, there 2 lib you can choose from:

[ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)
or
[ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

They are two different projects by two different project teams that are trying to accomplish more or less the same thing - allowing you to use Bootstrap in Angular (2+) without the use of jQuery.

They are both rebuilding the Bootstrap components using only Angular (no jQuery).The main differences are around which version of Bootstrap they support.

ngx-bootstrap supports Bootstrap 3 and 4.
ng-bootstrap supports Bootstrap 4 and requires Angular 5+.

Please refer to this thread for more detail:
[What is the difference between "ng-bootstrap" and "ngx-bootstrap"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758400/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-bootstrap-and-ngx-bootstrap)

Comment: Hi, I need to use only the styling I don't need animation. Any idea why it doesn't work in my way?

Comment: Where did you get this issue? Because i tried it on my local, it works perfectly. I try to create a stackblitz, it have to install jquery as peer dependency although i do not need it. If i do not install jquery, the bootstrap cannot be installed correctly. I think it should be an issue with stackblitz. Because i can easily add bootstrap with no issue on my local, and your code works perfectly on local.