# "Angular powered bootstrap" is "ngx-bootstrap"?

Tags: ng-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am making a project using ["Angular powered Bootstrap"](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), but after 4 weeks of development I found out that there is also something like ["ngx-bootstrap"](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/).

- Are they the same thing? - If not, then which one of them is
  `ng-bootstrap` ?
- Is `ngx-bootstrap` dead ?

Comment: ngx-bootstrap is developed by valor team, while ng-bootstrap is developed by pkozlowski and his team

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are completely 2 separate projects run by 2 different teams. ng-bootstrap is here:

- demo: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/
- GitHub: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

You should do your own investigations and decide which projects fits your needs better. As for any project being "dead" - you can get sense of projects state by evaluating frequency of commits, number of open issues and PRs, no of downloads on npm etc. Ultimately it is your own responsibility to choose libraries that you are planning to use.

Answer (score 4):

ngx-bootstrap is definitely not dead, at the moment we are working on v2 of it

- demo: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/
- github: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap
- npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap

may one of the main differences of ngx vs ng, that ng supports bootstrap 4 only, while ngx-bootstrap supports bs3 and bs4